# Call notepad doesn't work in rebol nor red on Windows 10

Tags: rebol, red

I type this in console:

call "notepad.exe"

It returns a number but notepad is not launched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `call` will hide the child process window, as it is often a system shell window. Use the `/show` refinement to force the called process to display its window:

```
call/show "notepad.exe"
```